# C++ order of operation during multiplication

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple program in C++ and I noticed that when I switch the order while multiplying some numbers i get 2 different outputs and can't figure out why it's happening.

```
void multiplier()
{
  double r, v1, v2;
  cout << "Enter the value of r" << endl;
  cin >> r;
  v1 = 4/3*M_PI*r*r*r;
  cout << v1 << endl;
  v2 = M_PI*4/3*r*r*r;
  cout << v2 << endl;
}
```

The second output is the corret one according to the calculator.

Comment: What do you think `4/3` does?  How does that compare to `4.0/3.0`?

Comment: See [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and [Order of Evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) on cppreference.com

Comment: Ohh thank you so int division returns the rest of the two. And in the second one im multiplying a float by an int so it converts it into a float, am I right?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I do not think order of evaluation matters here, but associativity

Comment: Parenthesis would very much clarify the formula `v1 = (4 * M_PI * r * r * r)/3;`. As M_PI should be a double constant you're always safe from errors caused by integer division problems.

Comment: Who is this... calculator you speak of? 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening here is the difference between integer division and floating-point divison. Multiplication and division are interpreted left to right. In the first case, the `4/3` is read first. When you write `4/3`, the compiler interprets that as an integer division, which would return `1`. However, in the second case, the `M_PI*4` makes the current value into a `double`, so when you divide by 3 next, the program performs a floating-point division, giving you the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication and division group left to right. That means that the first expression is treated as `4/3` times some other stuff. 4/3 is 1, and that’s what the other stuff gets multiplied by. The second expression is `M_PI*4` divided by some other stuff. The question doesn’t mention what `M_PI` is, but if it’s a floating-point type, the result of the multiplication is a floating-point type, and dividing it by 3 is floating-point division. That would account for getting different results.

Comment: It's the formula for the volume of a sphere so I think it's safe to say it's in fact a floating point type, more specifically the PI constant.

Comment: @anastaciu — it’s the other way around: if `M_PI` is the value of pi, then the formula is calculating the volume of a sphere. <g> That’s a reasonable guess, but the question doesn’t say that.

Comment: I can't argue with that.

Answer (score -2):

Use brackets to seperate multiplication values, this way you can allow certain calculations to be completes as oppose to interrupted or confused with another

```
((4/3)*M_PI)*r*r*r
```

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question posed by the OP.  It is more of a comment than an answer.  Also, `(4/3)` is still an integer.

Comment: The parentheses here restate the rules that the compiler would apply. Multiplication and division group left to right, and that's what the parentheses partially show. So, yes, it's an illustration of what the problem is, but that's not what the answer says.

Comment: I don’t have the reputation to post a comment but felt leaving that using parenthesis whenever doing multiple calculations is always useful to get the correct answer